# haml syntax - nesting partial properties

Tags: ruby, arrays, haml, staticmatic

what i want is a way of nesting partial properties, this seems a tad long winded:

```
= partial('frames/tabs_a', :locals => {:tabs_title => 'semi-dynamic-tabs',
  :tabs_id => 'p001',
  :panel_a => 'views/article-highlights_a',
  :a_id => 'p_002_0',
  :a_ft => '123 More in highlights',
  :a_tt => 'panel a', 
  :a_c => 'magazine', 
  :panel_b => 'views/thumbnail-list_a', 
  :b_id => 'b_id',
  :b_ft => 'testing tt', 
  :b_tt => 'panel b', 
  :b_c => 'opportunities', 
  :b_c => 'opportunities', 
  :panel_c => 'views/thumbnail-list_a', 
  :c_id => 'b_id', 
  :c_ft => 'testing tt',
  :c_tt => 'panel c',
  :c_c => 'community', 
  :panel_d => 'views/article-highlights_a',
  :d_id => 'p_002_0',
  :d_ft => '123 More in highlights',
  :d_tt => 'panel d', 
  :d_c => 'magazine'
})
```

I'm using staticmatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great place to write a helper.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks nex3, you are right, I'll probably end up doing that, however just in case this helps anybody, I did find the syntax for adding arrays to a hash.

```
=partial('_views/sub-nav', :locals => {:id => "x007", :menu_title => "Magazine", :selected_li => "Donkeys", :ul => ['Articles', 'Donkeys', 'Camels']})
```